# How to import Mozilla PDF.js in Vue project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

The question is simple. How do I correctly import the PDF.js library into a Vuejs project?

The library is `undefined` when I log it.

[See my problem in a codesandbox live here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-volhard-rnc3n?file=/src/components/PdfReader.vue:160-199).

This is how I am trying it now:

```
<script>
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
// import { PDFViewer } from "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer";
import "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.0.943/build/pdf.worker.min.js";

export default {
  name: "PdfViewer",
  mounted() {
    pdfjsLib.getDocument("./sample.pdf").then((doc) => {
      console.log("doc: ", doc);
    });
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

But that gives me the following error: `Cannot read property 'GlobalWorkerOptions' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

I think the error occurs if pdfjsLib does not fall into the global scope
, see also [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-frog-llble?file=/src/components/PdfReader.vue:256-374) :

```
<template>
  <div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import { PDFViewer } from "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer";
import "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.css";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.0.943/build/pdf.worker.min.js";

export default {
  name: "PdfViewer",
  props: { docPath: String },
  mounted() {
    this.getPdf();
  },
  methods: {
    async getPdf() {
      let container = document.getElementById("pageContainer");
      let pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({
        container: container,
      });
      let pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.docPath);
      pdfViewer.setDocument(pdf);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#pageContainer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

div.page {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

use it:

```
<PdfViewer docPath="./sample.pdf" />
```

Comment: `Parsing error: Identifier 'pdfjsLib' has already been declared` :(. I was referred to this document regarding importing the library, since it has changed recently: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/helloworld.html . But that doesn't seem to be working for me and I don't know why.

Comment: yes you can not use same var name if it was imported

Comment: this live example page: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

Comment: I tried with `var pdfjsLib2 = window["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"];
pdfjsLib2.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "...url";`, but that didnt work also.

Comment: check that your import works properly (pdfjsLib is not undefined)

Comment: but better remove the import and use `script` tag `<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>`

Comment: The lib is undefined when I log it... You can't use script tags in Vuejs as far as I know. Or it has to be added with javascript code in the `created()` hook. See here a reproduction of my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-volhard-rnc3n?file=/src/components/PdfReader.vue:160-199

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227412/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-reinier68).

Comment: if this was solved in the chat discussion.. could you please post the solution? @DaniilLoban

Comment: @syats I downgraded to `2.0.943` and it worked. Here is the example https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-frog-llble?file=/src/components/PdfReader.vue:679-687

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else needs it, the soution is really simple. You just have to import it like this:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

**`Pdf.js`** provide a solution for us. [**Webpack.js**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/blob/75158b4de095a6ce6c13fe165f98810ca9e63be6/webpack.js) included in the project.

```
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/webpack");
```

If you get an error like below:

```
./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.min.js 22:36927
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:36927)
```

Then we have to use **`es5/build/pdf.js`**, so we can create `src/pdfjs-webpack.js` :

```
"use strict";

var pdfjs = require("pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.min.js");
var PdfjsWorker = require("worker-loader?esModule=false&filename=[name].js!pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.worker.min.js");

if (typeof window !== "undefined" && "Worker" in window) {
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new PdfjsWorker();
}

module.exports = pdfjs;
```

then:

```
const pdfjsLib = require("../pdfjs-webpack");
```

Comment: In recent releases of pdfjs , "es5" folder has been renamed to "legacy"

Answer (score 1):

`vue-cli5` already use `webpack5`, and `webpack5` has a built-in [`web worker`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) and is very easy to use.

Create a file: `pdfjs-webpack5.js`

```js
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist'

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new Worker(new URL('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js', import.meta.url))

export default pdfjsLib
```

According to the example [`getinfo.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/14e8167df98efd38e8e163932c04f2d5238c5ffa/examples/node/getinfo.js#L11-L76) given in [`Setup PDF.js in a website`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website#npm), you can easily read the contents of PDF files.

I use the version of the package.

```
pdfjs-dist: 2.15.349
webpack: 5.74.0
@vue/cli*: 5.0.8
```

Comment: Did you test this? If so I will accept the answer.

Comment: After testing, this is the code written for today's work.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use the other answers, so I used `viewer.html` inside an iframe.

1. download the latest library from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases
2. Unzip it. Move the whole `pdfjs` directory inside the `public` directory of your project.
3. Use this code inside your `vue` template.

```html
    <iframe
      src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/path-to-the-file.pdf"
      :width="500px"
      :height="500px"
      frameborder="0"
    ></iframe>
```

You don't need to import anything inside the js.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a more complete solution and prefer embedding with `iframe`, consider using [`pdfjs-viewer-element`](https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element), the web component wrapper for PDF.js default viewer.

Vue has perfect support for Custom Elements, the only one thing you should do is tell your bundler that it is a web component, see [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components):

1. Download [PDF.js release](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases), unzip, and copy the folder with files to the project.
2. Install `pdfjs-viewer-element`:

`npm install pdfjs-viewer-element`

or using a browser:

`<script type="module" src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/pdfjs-viewer-element"></script>`

3. Add web component with attributes to your page:

`<pdfjs-viewer-element src="/file.pdf" viewer-path="/path-to-viewer"></pdfjs-viewer-element>`

Where:

`src` - Path to pdf file

`viewer-path` - path to unpacked release folder

There are more attributes you can pass:

`locale` - Specifies which language to use in the viewer UI

`text-layer` - Text layer, that is used for text selection
`page` - Page number

`search` - Search text

`phrase` - Search by phrase

`zoom` - Zoom level

`pagemode` - Page mode thumbs

`viewer-css-theme` - Apply automatic, light or dark theme

`viewer-extra-styles` - Add your CSS rules to the viewer application

See complete example: https://replit.com/@alekswebnet/Vue-3-pdfjs-viewer-element

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two ways to integrate pdf.js: embedding with iframe or building from scratch based on the `pdfjs-dist`.

If you have limited knowledge of the pdf.js project, it is better to use the iframe solution. However, the iframe solution may not be suitable if you require custom features, as it can be difficult to communicate with iframes and make the process more complicated. Building from scratch may seem like a good option initially, but if you want a fully-featured and performant PDF viewer like the default viewer provided by pdf.js, believe me, it requires a significant amount of work and the final result may not be as good.

I did some work and provide a third way to integrate the pdf.js default viewer to any project easily. You can use `@document-kits/viewer` like a normal npm package, and you can quickly start a project in minutes use `npm create`, now it support vue, lit and solid.

```bash
npm create @document-kits/viewer@latest my-app

# There will be prompt to let you choose a template to start,
# currently support lit, vue and solid.

cd my-app

# install dependencies
npm install

# run the dev server and open the default browser to view the demo
npm run dev --open
```

**It still use the 3.x of pdf.js, I will upgrade to 4.x it I have time**.