# How to use PDF.js with vue 3 with distribution folder on local

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3, pdf.js

**Please understand this, I am not allowed to use any vue liberary for previewing pdf, I can only use pure pdf.js and vue 3**

- I am using `pdf.js` for displaying pdf file on my `vue 3` project.
- I want to know how should I do folder stucturing of the project to make it work.
- Currently I am using `cdnjs` link of `pdf.js`, I want to use there

> [distribution folder](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

instead of `cdnjs` link.

- Here is my current implementation with there example provided on [official website](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) of pdf.js.

### pdf-view.vue

```js
<template>
  <canvas :id="`the-canvas${index}`" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, defineProps } from 'vue'

const { file, index } = defineProps(['file', 'index'])

onMounted(() => {
  import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.0.379/pdf.mjs').then((pdfjsLib) => {
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.0.379/pdf.worker.min.mjs'

    if (!file) return

    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const array = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result)
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(array)
      loadingTask.promise.then(
        (pdf) => {
          const pageNumber = 1
          pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then((page) => {
            const scale = 1.5
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale })

            const canvas = document.getElementById(`the-canvas${index}`)
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
            canvas.height = viewport.height
            canvas.width = viewport.width

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            const renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            }
            page.render(renderContext)
          })
        },
        (reason) => {
          // PDF loading error
          console.error(reason)
        }
      )
    }
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  })
})
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

### parent.vue

```
<template v-for="(file, index) in pdfFiles" :key="file">
            <pdfview :file="file.file" :index="index" />
</template>
<script setup>
import pdfview from '@/components/pdf-view/pdf-view.vue'
</script>
```

*Current folder stucture*

```
--Project
  -public
  -src
  --components
  ---pdf-view
  ----pdf-view.vue [component]
  ---views
  ----parent.vue [component]
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65750584/how-to-import-mozilla-pdf-js-in-vue-project

Comment: Sorry, for trouble @James, let me see that answer post if that works I will remove this post or repost answer here.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps I performed which solved my problem.

- Install pdfjs-dist.
- `npm install pdfjs-dist`
- Second step this is something you have to do, if you get below error,

> op-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

- It has to do with `vite.config.js` file.
- I found solution for that from [this post](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/17245).
  Add below code in your `vite.config.js` file.

```
build: {
    target: "es2022"
  },
  esbuild: {
    target: "es2022"
  },
  optimizeDeps:{
    esbuildOptions: {
      target: "es2022",
    }
  }
```

- Then you need to import file like this,

```
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";
import * as pdfWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs";
```

if you will not import second then you might get below error.

> pdfWorker is not defined